# A question about a linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

If $f(x)$ is a function with domain $R$ such that for all real $a, x$ it is $f(ax) =
af(x)$ then there exists a real number $b$ such that $f(x) = bx$ for all $x.$

How to prove this statement?

Comment: how to prove this question?

Answer (score 3):

We have $f(x)=f(1\cdot x) = xf(1)$ for all $x$

Comment: can you explain the details please. I can not relate your answer with "here exists a real number b such that f(x)=bx for all x."

Comment: @SupriyadiTasim: $f(1)$ is the real number you seek.

Comment: do you mean f(1) = b??

Comment: @SupriyadiTasim yes.